# Encountering a Mysterious 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content' Error in Python Script Using Selenium, Trafilatura, and LangChain

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, openai-api, langchain

I'm currently working on a Python script that involves web scraping using Selenium and Trafilatura, followed by text summarization using LangChain with Map Reduce. However, I've encountered a perplexing error that I'm unable to resolve. Despite reviewing my code multiple times, I can't seem to find any reference to the attribute causing the issue. I'm hoping to get some insights or suggestions from the community.

Error Message

```
Error fetching content from [URL]: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'
```

Script Overview:
The script's purpose is to scrape web content from a specified URL and then summarize this content using LangChain's summarization capabilities. Here's a simplified version of the script:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import trafilatura
import time

# Set your OpenAI API Key here
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "xxxx"

# Set up the options for Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def fetch_article_content(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)  # Wait for the page to load
    html = driver.page_source
    return trafilatura.extract(html)

# URLs to extract content from
urls = [
    "https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/products-and-innovation/the-dx-and-fx-formats.html"
]

# Initialize LangChain LLM
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-1106')
query = "DX vs FX"

for url in urls:
    try:
        text = fetch_article_content(url)
        if text is None or len(text) < 500:
            print(f"Source {url}: No Result or Insufficient Content")
        else:
            # Check the length of the text
            if len(text) > 10000:
                text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10000, chunk_overlap=500)
                chunks = text_splitter.create_documents([text])

                map_custom_prompt = '''
                Summarize the following text to answer {query} in a clear and concise way:
                TEXT:`{text}`
                Brief Summary:
                '''
                map_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
                    input_variables=['text', 'query'],
                    template=map_custom_prompt
                )

                combine_custom_prompt = '''
                Generate a summary of the following text that includes the following elements:

                * A title that accurately reflects the content of the text.
                * An introduction paragraph that provides an overview of the topic.
                * Bullet points that list the key points of the text.
                * A conclusion paragraph that summarizes the main points of the text.

                Text:`{text}`
                '''
                combine_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
                    template=combine_custom_prompt, 
                    input_variables=['text', 'query']
                )

                summary_chain = load_summarize_chain(
                    llm=llm,
                    chain_type='map_reduce',
                    map_prompt=map_prompt_template,
                    combine_prompt=combine_prompt_template,
                    verbose=False
                )
                summary = summary_chain.run(chunks)
            else:
                chain = load_summarize_chain(
                    llm,
                    chain_type='map_reduce',
                    verbose=False
                )
                summary = chain.run([text])

            print(f"Source {url}:\n{summary}\n\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching content from {url}: {e}")

driver.quit()
```

Code Review for 'page_content' Reference: I carefully reviewed the entire script to find any instance where a page_content attribute might be used or referenced. I expected to find a line of code where I mistakenly used this attribute on a string object. However, no such reference exists in my script.

Comment: Post the full traceback message so we can see where it came from.

Comment: similar error message, but I don't think the same problem: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3799